# apply.daterangepicker event stops firing when daterangepicker() constructor re-attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker version: 3.0.3

I have a radio button pair that lets the user switch between local and utc time. When I click on the radio button I want to remove and re-attach the daterangepicker constructor so I can specify different pre-defined date ranges.

However, after clicking on the radio button the daterangepicker stops firing an event when I click "Apply" or click on a pre-defined date range.

I made a simplified version of my program on jsfiddle and the apply event is still not firing

https://jsfiddle.net/flexmcmurphy/re62qhb8/4/

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test2.html</title>
    <script src="include/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="include/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="include/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="datetimes"/>
Local <input type="radio" name="timeformat" value="local" checked="checked"><span id="mybar">|</span><input type="radio" name="timeformat" value="utc"> UTC

<script>

// Global Variables
var selectedtimeformat;

// Set the selectedtimeformat variable on page load
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setSelectedTimeFormat();
    attachpicker();
});

$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='timeformat']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue != selectedtimeformat){
            setSelectedTimeFormat();
            if(selectedtimeformat == 'utc'){
                $('input[name="datetimes"]').data('daterangepicker').remove();
                attachpicker();
            }else{
                // Re-attach the DRP so the startDate, endDate, minDate and maxDate settings are updated for the UTC/local time choice
                $('input[name="datetimes"]').data('daterangepicker').remove();
                attachpicker();
            }
        }       
});  // end function $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){...}

function setSelectedTimeFormat(){
    selectedtimeformat = $("input[name='timeformat']:checked").val();
    alert("selectedtimeformat: " + selectedtimeformat);
}

function attachpicker(){

if(selectedtimeformat == 'local'){
    $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    "opens": 'right',
    "drops": 'down',
    "timePicker": true,
    "locale": {
      "format": 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    },
    "alwaysShowCalendars": true,    
    "ranges": {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "startDate": "04/08/2019",
    "endDate": "04/10/2019",
    "minDate": "04/05/2019",
    "maxDate": "04/18/2019",
    "timePickerIncrement": 10,
    "timePicker24Hour": true
    }); // <-- end of daterangepicker() constructor
}else{
// selectedtimeformat == 'utc'
    $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    "opens": 'right',
    "drops": 'down',
    "timePicker": true,
    "locale": {
      "format": 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    },
    "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
    "ranges": {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "startDate": "04/08/2019",
    "endDate": "04/14/2019",
    "minDate": "04/05/2019",
    "maxDate": "04/18/2019",
    "timePickerIncrement": 10,
    "timePicker24Hour": true
    }); // <-- end of daterangepicker() constructor
}

}   //<-- end of function attachpicker()

$('input[name="datetimes"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    alert("apply.daterangepicker event fired");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expected Result:**
When I change the selected radio button and then select a pre-defined date range or click "apply" in the daterangepicker the apply.daterangepicker event should fire and an alert() popup should appear showing the event has fired.

i.e: the daterangepicker constructor should be removed and re-attached with new properties.

This should happen because my attachpicker() method is called when the radio button is changed.

**Actual Result:**
Instead when I change the selected radio button and then select a pre-defined date range or click "apply" in the daterangepicker I don't get the alert pop up showing that the apply event fired.

However...

When I change the selected Radio Button the startDate and endDate that appears in the textbox DOES update correctly.

With Local Radio Button selected:
    "startDate": "04/08/2019"
    "endDate": "04/10/2019"

UTC Radio Button selected:
    "startDate": "04/08/2019"
    "endDate": "04/14/2019"

So this tells me the daterangepicker constructor does get re-attached with new properties just that the apply event stops firing.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove()` function you're calling removes any event listeners for the date range picker you're destroying.

Move your `apply.daterangepicker` listener creation into the `attachpicker()` function.